# Can もとい be used as a noun describing the correction or the fact of correction?

Tags: words

Can [元い{もとい}](http://kotobaknow.com/motoi) be used as a noun for actual correction (or the fact of correcting oneself), or does it imply actually saying the word もとい literally?

If someone describes their conduct using その時、元いを言った can it be used in both of the following situations:

> 1. あなたは４０歳もとい３０歳になって、〜
> 2. あなたは４０歳、失礼しました、３０歳になって、〜

or only the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, 「もとい」 cannot be used as a noun.  It can only be used as  an interjection.

Thus, you ***cannot*** say:

> 「その時、元い**を**言った。」

You ***can*** say:

> 「その時、『元い』**と**言った。」

If you must use a ***noun*** for some reason, you could say:

> 「訂正{ていせい}**を**した」 or
>
> 「言{い}い直{なお}し**を**した」

(Hope I am reading your question correctly.)